# How to perform arithmetic operations on a list of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm writing a function that takes in a list of lists and takes the head element in the list and compares it to every other element in the list of lists. I know using recursion is how to perform most actions on a list but I've been coming across some difficulties trying to translate this onto a list of lists. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
compareElements([H|T]) :-
    compareHeadList(H,T).

compareHeadList([H|T],RestOfList) :-
    compare(T,H,GreaterList,LesserList),
    compareRestList(RestOfList,H).

compareRestList(X,[HA|TA]) :-
    compare(HA,X,GreaterList,LesserList),
    compareRestList(X,TA).

compare([HA|TA],X,GreaterList,LesserList) :-
    X @> HA -> GreaterList = [HA|GreaterTail],
    compare(TA,X,GreaterTail,LesserList);
    LesserList = [HA|LesserTail],
    compare(TA,X,GreaterList,LesserTail).
compare([_|TA],X,GreaterList,LesserList) :-
    compare(TA,X,GreaterList,LesserList).
```

For Example:

```
    compareElements(LoL).
    Where Lol = [[6,4,8],[7,9,2],[1,3,0]]
    My Goal is to compare 6 with every other element in the Lol, 
    so that GreaterList = [8,7,9], and LesserList = [4,2,1,3,0]
```

My idea of how the code should run is compareElements() takes in a list of lists, then calls compareHeadList() to compare the head of the first list with the rest of the elements in that list. Finally, compareRestList() is supposed to take in the Head element to be compared and the rest of the list of lists, call the compare function, and return true.

My problem is when I writeLn() the lists to check the elements it's outputting sequences like "9c78" which seems like a memory address. I'm wondering if I'm comparing the elements properly and pushing them onto the list correctly or if there is another piece causing this to happen.

Comment: First concatenate the lists, and then perform arithmetic on the list of items.

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate a list of lists into a single list using the append function? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: yes, take a look at [**`append/2`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2).

Comment: @JoshPokorny You want the output as true or a list of all numbers that are greater and lesser for each number? For example for 6 GL=[1,2,3] LL=[18,39,40].

Comment: @ReemaQKhan My goal is to just output true but I'm using the lists and writeLn() to try and test my functions to see if they are working correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
head_head([[X|_]|_], X).

split_list(_, [], [], []).
split_list(K, [H|T],     G, S) :- H = K, split_list(K, T, G, S).
split_list(K, [H|T], [H|G], S) :- H > K, split_list(K, T, G, S).
split_list(K, [H|T], G, [H|S]) :- H < K, split_list(K, T, G, S).

split_lol(X, G, S) :- head_head(X, K), append(X, L), split_list(K, L, G, S).
```

Test:

```
?- split_lol([[6,4,8],[7,9,2],[1,3,0]], G, S).
G = [8, 7, 9],
S = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0] .

?-
```

---

Some kewl "backwards" functionality Prolog gives you:

```
?- split_lol([[6,X,Y], [A, B]], [7, 8], [2, 1]).
X = 7,
Y = 8,
A = 2,
B = 1 ;
X = 7,
Y = 2,
A = 8,
B = 1 ;
X = 7,
Y = 2,
A = 1,
B = 8 ;
X = 2,
Y = 7,
A = 8,
B = 1 ;
X = 2,
Y = 7,
A = 1,
B = 8 ;
X = 2,
Y = 1,
A = 7,
B = 8 ;
false.

?-
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can be made to work. For a hint on what is missing, see these warnings emitted by Prolog:

```
Warning: /home/isabelle/lol.pl:4:
    Singleton variables: [GreaterList,LesserList]
Warning: /home/isabelle/lol.pl:8:
    Singleton variables: [GreaterList,LesserList]
```

Singleton variable warnings are **serious**. They tell you that you have made the kind of typo that typically makes a program meaningless, or (as in this case) that you have not yet connected some parts of the computation with others. In your program, even when you compute the greater/lesser lists for one of the nested lists, you never relate this to the greater/lesser lists for the other nested lists -- so you can never get a complete answer.

If the greater list for one of the lists is `[8]`, and for another list it's `[7, 9]`, then we somehow want to construct the total greater list of `[8, 7, 9]`. A common way in Prolog is to actually only compute *partial* lists: Lists where the tail is not `[]` but a variable. In the example, if we compute the partial list `[8 | Tail]`, and then ask for the next computation to be unified with `Tail`, we get a combined partial list of `[8, 7, 9 | Tail2]`. Unifying `Tail2` with `[]` will then close the list in the end.

Here is your code adapted to this approach, and using somewhat more explicit names:

```
list_element_greater_smaller([], _Y, GreaterTail, GreaterTail, SmallerTail, SmallerTail).
list_element_greater_smaller([X | Xs], Y, Greater, GreaterTail, Smaller, SmallerTail) :-
    (   X > Y
    ->  Greater = [X | Greater1],
        list_element_greater_smaller(Xs, Y, Greater1, GreaterTail, Smaller, SmallerTail)
    ;   Smaller = [X | Smaller1],
        list_element_greater_smaller(Xs, Y, Greater, GreaterTail, Smaller1, SmallerTail) ).

lists_element_greater_smaller([], _Y, GreaterTail, GreaterTail, SmallerTail, SmallerTail).
lists_element_greater_smaller([Xs | Xss], Y, Greater, GreaterTail, Smaller, SmallerTail) :-
    list_element_greater_smaller(Xs, Y, Greater, GreaterTail1, Smaller, SmallerTail1),
    lists_element_greater_smaller(Xss, Y, GreaterTail1, GreaterTail, SmallerTail1, SmallerTail).

lists_greater_smaller([[Y | Xs] | Xss], Greater, Smaller) :-
    lists_element_greater_smaller([Xs | Xss], Y, Greater, [], Smaller, []).
```

Take the time to understand how the `Tail` variables are threaded through all the computations and then closed off with `[]`.

This behaves as follows:

```
?- lists_greater_smaller([[6,4,8],[7,9,2],[1,3,0]], Greater, Smaller).
Greater = [8, 7, 9],
Smaller = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0].
```

As long as the nesting depth of the lists is fixed, there is also a simpler way to write all this: You can write a single recursive predicate over *nested* lists very similarly to how you do a recursion over a "flat" list. You will have three cases to distinguish:

- the overall outer list is empty
- the first nested list is empty
- the first nested list has some head and tail

This approach can look like this:

```
lists_greater_smaller2([[Y | Xs] | Xss], Greater, Smaller) :-
    lists_element_greater_smaller2([Xs | Xss], Y, Greater, Smaller).

lists_element_greater_smaller2([], _Y, [], []).
lists_element_greater_smaller2([[] | Xss], Y, Greater, Smaller) :-
    lists_element_greater_smaller2(Xss, Y, Greater, Smaller).
lists_element_greater_smaller2([[X | Xs] | Xss], Y, Greater, Smaller) :-
    (   X > Y
    ->  Greater = [X | Greater1],
        lists_element_greater_smaller2([Xs | Xss], Y, Greater1, Smaller)
    ;   Smaller = [X | Smaller1],
        lists_element_greater_smaller2([Xs | Xss], Y, Greater, Smaller1) ).
```

And again:

```
?- lists_greater_smaller2([[6,4,8],[7,9,2],[1,3,0]], Greater, Smaller).
Greater = [8, 7, 9],
Smaller = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0] ;
false.
```