# How to correct this 'Greater Than' Arithmetic Prolog code?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a simple prolog program where a number is compared with the elements in a list. To check that the number is greater than which elements in the list, and it simply returns the list with the elements that are less than the number. Example: gt(12,[19,4,6,22],L), this should return L = [4,6].

Here is my attempt:

```
gt(_,[],[]):-!.
gt(Num,[H|T],[H|L]):-
    Num>H,  
    gt(Num,T,L).
gt(Num,[H|T],[H|L]):-
    Num=<H,!,  
    gt(Num,T,L).
```

The problem that I am facing is in the =< predicate. If the condition is =< the number, then I am trying to say that ignore and move to the next number gt(Num,T,L). The place where I have written L, what should I write here so that it understands that I don't want you to write that value in the list?
Works alright for values that are already smaller than the number.

```
?-gt(12,[6,7,6],L).
L = [6,7,6]
```

But fail for such tests:

```
?- gt(12,[19,6,7],L).
L = [19, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Looks like a subproblem of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848337/how-to-perform-arithmetic-operations-on-a-list-of-lists-in-prolog/64849340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the third parameter in the third clause of `gt/3`. It is also "adding" the current item `H` as the head of the output list.
You should write

```
gt(Num,[H|T],L):-
    Num=<H,!,  
    gt(Num,T,L).
```

instead.

You may also get rid of those cuts (`!`) to make your procedure work with other modes for the parameters and/or with uninstantiated variables.